# I am trying to lock a table name tb1 but unable to lock using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mariadb

[image]

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 0)

Comment: MySQL or mariaDB?

Comment: Its mariadatabase

Comment: Why do you 'need' to lock a table?  I ask because there may be another way to achieve the real goal.